# how to delete files with specific date pattern

Tags: linux, shell-script, find, regular-expression

Under the folder `/var/log/roler_t`, we have the following files:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 roler smike    37652 Jun 25 01:44 2018-06-23T02:KJU:00
-rw-r--r-- 1 roler smike    41742 Jun 25 01:45 2018-06-21T20:KJU:00
-rw-r--r-- 1 roler smike    36762 Jun 25 01:46 2018-06-22T08:KJU:00
-rw-r--r-- 1 roler smike    51764 Jun 25 01:47 PL-06-23T12:KJU:00
-rw-r--r-- 1 roler smike    42751 Jun 25 01:48 2018-06-21T16:KJU:00
-rw-r--r-- 1 roler smike    34627 Jun 25 01:49 2018-06-22T23:KJU:00
-rw-r--r-- 1 roler smike    59828 Jun 25 01:51 2018-06-23T05:KJU:00
-rw-r--r-- 1 roler smike    33561 Jun 25 01:52 2018-06-22T20:KJU:00
-rw-r--r-- 1 roler smike    59828 Jun 25 01:51 JFG:KJU:00
-rw-r--r-- 1 roler smike    33561 Jun 25 01:52 PL-22T20:KJU:00
-rw-r--r-- 1 roler smike    36643 Jun 25 01:53 2018-06-22T01:KJU:00
```

How can we remove only the files that are older than ten days and have a specific date pattern, for example `2018-06-23`.

**Expected results are as follows:**

the following files will stay under `/var/log/roler_t`

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 roler smike    51764 Jun 25 01:47 PL-06-23T12:KJU:00
-rw-r--r-- 1 roler smike    59828 Jun 25 01:51 JFG:KJU:00
-rw-r--r-- 1 roler smike    33561 Jun 25 01:52 PL-22T20:KJU:00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter your files by date with the `find` command.

For example:

```
find /var/log/roler_t -mtime +10
```

returns all files with *modification date* > 10 days.

Similarly you can use flags like `-atime` (access time), `-ctime` (status change time), but I think `-mtime` is what you're looking for.

If you want to remove them with a single command (but I suggest you **always** check before if the results of `find` are what you're expecting):

```
find /var/log/roler_t -mtime +10 -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: not as I ask , I mean to delete all files with name date syntax as xxxx-xx-xx , and that older then 10day

Comment: the syntax find /var/log/roler_t -mtime +10 -exec rm {} \; , will remove also the file as PL-22T20:KJU:00

Comment: @yael as @B.McCready answered, then just filter by filename, too adding `-name "*XXXX-XX-XX*" to the `find` command.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to your earlier question, you can achieve this by the following

```
$ find /var/log/roler_t -mtime +10 -name "XXXX-XX-XX*"
```

where XXXX-XX-XX is the datestamp you are looking for. If you **know** that the year month and day correspond to the modification time you are looking for you coul change the  argument to the -name option to be something like this:

```
$find /var/log/roler_t -mtime +10 -name "`date -d'now - 10 days' +'%y-%m-%d'*"
```

to automatically generate the filename prefix, though you may need to play with the date command number of days you subtract to be sue the mtime and the datestamp match what you need.

If you just want to match the names of files that begin with a datestamp like string, e.g. '2018-09-13' then use the following:

```
/var/log/roler_t -mtime +10 -name "[12][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[01][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]*"
```

Comment: but XXXX-XX-XX can be 1998-02-34 or 2013-01-56 , etc  , so the option "-name "XXXX-XX-XX*" must to fit to any date

Comment: @yael, are you saying there might be files of varying age and datestamps, but you only want to delete the ones whose names begin with a datestamp in the form of YYYY-MM-DD? then just change the -name option argument to "[12][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[01][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]*" or similar.

Comment: yes thats I mean

Comment: @yael I think I get what you're saying; you want the filename to match a pattern? You can do that via ‘-name '????-??-??‘ or  ‘-name "[0-9][0-9]0-9][0-9]-[0-9] (etc)‘ or also see the 'regex‘ option https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19111067/regex-match-either-string-in-linux-find-command

Comment: so can you please update the answer , instead the remark so I will choose the right answer

Comment: "hard-coding" the "now - 10 days" would tell `find` to look for files that are named with 10-days-ago, and would not "find" those named 9, 8, 7, etc days ago.